# Build system when using auto scaling group with ELB in aws

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration

I was using a free tier aws account in which I had one ec2 machine (Linux). I have a simple website with backend server running on django at 8000 port and front end server written in angular and running on http (80) port. I used nginx for https and redirection of calls to backend and frontend server.

Now for backend build system, I did these 3 main steps (which I automated by running jenkins on the same machine).

```
1) git pull (Pull the latest code from repo).
2) Do migrations (Updating my db with any new table).
3) Restarting the django server. (I was using gunicorn).
```

Now, I split my front end and backend server into 2 different machines using auto scaling groups and I am now using ELB (Aws Elastic Load balancer) to route the requests. I am done with the setup. But now I am having problem in continuous deployment. The main thing is that ELB uses auto scaling groups which in turn uses AMI.

Now, since AMI's are created once, my first question is how to automate this process and deploy my latest code in already running aws servers.

Second, if I want to run few steps just once for all the servers like my second step of updating db with new tables then how to achieve that.

And also third if these steps need to run on a machine, then do I need to have another ec2 instance to automate the process of creating AMI, updating auto scaling groups with it and then deploying latest code in that.

So, basically I want to know the best practices that people follow in deploying latest code in aws machines that were created by auto scaling groups with the help of AMI. Also I use bitbucket for code management.

Comment: Have you looked at AWS CodeDeploy?

Answer (score 3):

**First Question**: how to automate 'package based deployment'.

Instead of creating a new AMI for every release, create a baseline AMI which only changes when your new release require OS changes / security patches / etc. Look into tools such as [packer](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon.html) to create AMIs automatically. In order to automate your code deployment when it changes, you can use a package-based deployment approach, which means you create a package for every release (Should be part of your CI process), which is stored in some repository such as Nexus, Artifactory, or even a simple S3 bucket.
When you deploy a new instance of your application, it should run some sort of script to pull and unpack/install that package on the instance < this is the basic concept, there are many tools that can help you achieve this, for example, Chef, or AWS CloudFormation.
So essentially, Step 1 should pull the code, create the package and store it in some repository available to your application servers > this can be done offline.

**Second Question**: How to run other tasks such as updating database schema.

As mentioned above, this can also be part of your 'deployment' automation, so if you are using Chef or even a simple bash script, it can update a database schema before unpacking the new code, this really depends on your database, how you manage it, and who orchestrates the deployment.

For example, you could have a Jenkins job that pulls the new schema and updates your database when ever you rollout a release.

Your third question can be solved by Packer, it can spin up instances, create an AMI, and terminate the instance.

Read more into CICD, and CICD related tools.